# re-indexing a search engine every few minutes

Tags: php, windows, sphinx

I'm running a search service on my development computer, and I have to run an indexer (.exe file) and restart a service every 1-5 minutes (I'm using sphinx search).
How would I go about doing this in Windows? My thought is to run a batch file through windows task scheduler, but what do you do?

Comment: adamcroft:

Just out of curiousity, is it really necessary to restart the sphinx search daemon under windows? we use sphinx on linux servers and it does not require a restart of anything. the indexer will automatically generate the new index files and rotate them with the old ones once finished.

Comment: yes, for some reason i experience a very strange error when i don't restart searchd. I suddenly begin to get results with doc id's that haven't yet been reached. (for example - the autoincrement on the PK is at 70, and I get search results with a docid of 200). any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Windows Task Scheduler` while in Windows. Use `cron` while in Linux.

Otherwise, you could write a daemon process which would sleep in an infinite loop for a specified interval and re-index once the interval is over. Then again, it would sleep and continue the process.

For example (in Perl):

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Proc::Daemon;

Proc::Daemon::Init;

my $minutes = 5;
my $seconds = 60 * $minutes;

while (1) {
    sleep($seconds);
    # Do necessary work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found pycron quite helpful as a replacement for the built in task scheduler. If you are used to the unix cron style you'll love it from the beginnig. It has an editable config file and logfiles and more options.

An article about it: http://www.bigbluehost.com/article4.html

Pycron's website: http://www.kalab.com/freeware/pycron/pycron.htm